# Is std::optional<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> good for avoiding null point deference?

Tags: c++

I want to write safe C++ programs, therefore:

I wanted to avoid memory leaks, so I started using `std::shared_ptr`.

However, I still had some null pointer deferences some times. I've come up with the idea of using `using MyClassSafe = std::optional<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>>`.

Then I avoid both memory leaks and null pointer deference. Well, kind of. For example:

```
MyClassSafe myClassSafe = std::make_shared<MyClass>();
//Then everytime I want to use myClassSafe:
if (myClassSafe) {
    //use it here
} else {
    //do something in case no value
}

//However, this situation can be possible:
MyClassSafe notVerySafe = std::make_shared<MyClass>(nullptr); // or = std::shared_ptr(nullptr);
if (myClassSafe) {
    //use it here, for example:
    //this deferences a nullptr
    myClassSafe.value()->someFunction();
} else {
    //do something in case no value
}
```

so this is not much safer. It's better but I still can make mistakes.

I can imagine a `safe_shared_ptr<T>` class that instead of calling the object's functions on `operator->`, it could return `std::optional<T&>` (much like Rust) for which we can then safely call or deal with the `std::nullopt` case. Isn't there something already in C++? Or can it be implemented easily?

Comment: Either `std::optional` or `std::shared_ptr`. When you nest monads you get two potentially null references for the price of one.

Answer (score 1):

`optional<T>` allows you to handle the "no T available" case, which `shared_ptr<T>` already handles. Therefore `optional<shared_ptr<T>>` is redundant, just like `optional<optional<T>>` is.

There is a case to be made for `shared_ptr<optional<T>>` - if one owner creates the `T` object, the other owner can see the new object, so that isn't really redundant.

Comment: It might be cases whereas `nullptr` is valid value, so optional might make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown need for *either* pointers or optionals here.

```
MyClass myClassSafe;
myClassSafe.someFunction();
```

No possibility of null pointers or empty optionals in sight.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `std::optional` here is the cause of the problem. `std::shared_ptr` defines `operator bool` as a null pointer check, but because you have wrapped it in `std::optional` this never gets called

If instead you try:

```
MyClass myClass = std::make_shared<MyClass>(nullptr); // or = std::shared_ptr(nullptr);
if (myClass) {
    // std::shared_ptr implements operator bool as a null pointer check
    myClass->someFunction();
} else {
    //do something in case no value
}
```

Comment: But `std::shared_ptr` does not force me to do the `if` thing. With `std::optional` I must call `.value()` so I know I should check if it has a value

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs: `std::optional` has also (unsafe) [`operator ->`/ `operator*`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator*).

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't there something already in C++?

There is nothing in std to handle non null smart pointer.

As Caleth shows in his answer, you can use object directly and avoid (smart) pointer and `std::optional`.

> Or can it be implemented easily?

Non null smart pointer (a "smart reference" :) ) should be non default constructible, and "non-movable" (I mean move should not invalidate the reference).

You could implement it with existing smart pointer, something like:

```
template <typename T>
class unique_ref
{
public:
    // Avoid variadic constructor which might take precedence over regular copy/move constructor
    // so I use tag std::in_place_t here.
    template <typename ... Ts>
    unique_ref(std::in_place_t, Ts&&... args) : std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...) {}

    unique_ref(const unique_ref&) = delete;
    unique_ref(unique_ref&&) = delete;

    unique_ref& operator=(const unique_ref&) = delete;
    unique_ref& operator=(unique_ref&&) = delete;

    const T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }
    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }

    const T* operator ->() const { return ptr.get(); }
    T* operator*() { return ptr.get(); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
};

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
unique_ref<T> make_unique_ref(Ts&&... args)
{
    return {std::in_place, std::forward<Ts>(args)...};
}
```

unique version is not much useful, as non-copyable, non-movable. using directly `T` seems simpler.

shared version is copyable (its move should do identical to the copy)
A weak version might return an `std::optional<shared_ref<T>>`.